# Python if statement inside for loop

Tags: python, syntax

I'm expecting to get "is null", because var0 is equal zero and the if statement shall print is null! Is is a syntax mistake?

```
var0 = 0
var1 = 1
var2 = 2

for i in range(3):
    if f"var{i}" == 0:
        print("is null")
```

I'm not getting any output.

Comment: Try using eval(). `if eval(f"var{i}") == 0:`

Comment: Hi, here the  ``f"var{i}"`` take as var0 a string comparing with 0. Hence it giving you False. try eval() to convert to variable

Comment: Your formatting produces strings that look like `'var0'`and `'var1'`, you’re not using the variables themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future seekers, comment as answer:

```
var0 = 0
var1 = 1
var2 = 2

for i in range(3):
    if eval(f"var{i}") == 0:
        print("is null")
```

Result:

> is null

Comment: Do you know what is wrong here `sx.set_attribute(v1="test",**{f"v{i}": None for i in range(19) if val(f"v{i}") == ""})`

Comment: it giving me >NameError: name 'v0' is not defined    **the vars I must assign are var0 ... var18**

Answer (score 0):

Better to use list like below

```
var0 = 0
var1 = 1
var2 = 2

list = [var0, var1, var2]

for i in range(len(list)): #or range(3)
    if list[i] == 0:
        print("is null")
```

Comment: I actually need this to assign to a function many vars. `sx.set_attribute(v1="test",**{f"v{i}": None for i in range(0,19) if val(f"v{i}") == 0})`  All not field vars shall be field with None.

Comment: @mathandlogic there has to be a better way to do what you’re doing if you 'need' eval. It sounds like you have 18 separate variables that could have just been a list.

Comment: @wkl I now see what you mean. I didnt know before that we can assign a list to a function. I this solve my problem I will accept your answer. Thx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the below codes

```
var0 = 0
var1 = 1
var2 = 2

for i in range(3):
    if str(i) == "0":
        print("is null")
```

OR

```
var0 = 0
var1 = 1
var2 = 2

for i in range(3):
    if i == 0:
        print("is null")
```

Comment: it works, result:- is null

Comment: in the original code f'val{i}' is val0 and it is not equal to '0'

Comment: I hope it answers

Comment: could you please take a look at this here `sx.set_attribute(v5="somehostname",**{f"v{i}": None for i in range(19) if eval(f"v{i}") == ""})`

Comment: it giving me **NameError: name 'v0' is not defined**

Comment: Idk what is wrong here. I simply want to fill all required args with "None" if they are empty. I will accept your answer. If you tell me what's wrong here!